# How can I send a key event with known Unicode character to an Android app using InputConnection without kcm?

Tags: android, android-source, keyboard-events, keyevent

I am currently using `InputConnection`. I wish to mimic the effect that a key event happened on a physical keyboard even though I am actually programming an input method. So `InputConnection.commitText` is not a solution.

I am trying `InputConnection.sendKeyEvent`. I know the scan code, key code, and the unicode character it should map to, i.e., what `event.getUnicodeChar()` should return (because they are all obtained on a remote device and received over the network). <s>I found that `KeyEvent.getUnicodeChar` is not used when the event is handled, so overriding this method didn't help.</s> updated.

How can I achieve this effect that, a key event can be constructed and handled so that the correct known unicode character can be inserted (if editing text)?

Considtions:

1. Note that I know the character for this key event, not a key character map or the information about the complete keyboard layout.
2. I am open to alternatives to using `KeyEvent` constructors, but I must supply all three -- scan code, key code, unicode character -- to simulate the real physical key event.

---

I tried modifying source of `KeyEvent` so that it returns my unicode point value, I find that the right character is inserted. That tells me `getUnicodeChar` is indeed used and is what I am looking for. However, some debug logging reveals that the event object being handled in `ViewRootImpl#ViewRootHandler#handleMessage` is not the one I created and sent via `InputConnection.sendKeyEvent`, because the executed `getUnicodeChar` method is not the one I override. I don't understand why and how to proceed.